# In Romyar Sharifi's Group Cohomology Notes, why is it true that $H^0(G,A) = A^G$ the group of $G$-invariants of the $G$-module $A$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-explanation, homology-cohomology, group-cohomology

Firstly, the book doesn't really say what $C^{-1}(G, A)$ is so how can I take it's image under $d^{-1}$ in order to compute $H^0(G,A) = \ker d^0 / \text{im } d^{-1}$?

[https://www.math.ucla.edu/~sharifi/groupcoh.pdf](https://www.math.ucla.edu/%7Esharifi/groupcoh.pdf)  (remark on page 7)

Can someone please explain this trivial but important remark?

Wikipedia does the same thing as the book:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_cohomology#Definitions

It just states that $H^0(G,A)$ is taken to be $A^G$.

(Edit: They give a proof in the next paragraph ! :)

Comment: There is no $C^{-1}$, or if you like it is zero. So $d^{-1} = 0$ and $H^0 = \ker d^0$ only. Then it's a direct computation to see that $\ker d^0$ computes invariants.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The notes say explicitly (Definition 1.2.4. ii) that $B^0(G,A)$ should be taken to be $0$ (i.e. the set consisting of the zero map), and so $H^0(G,A) = Z^0(G,A)$. $C^{-1}(G,A)$ and $d^{-1}$ are both undefined. The notes also tell you to consider $G^0$ to be the singleton set, and so $C^0(G,A)$ is identified with $A$ (i.e. $f\in C^0(G,A)$ is being identified with $f(*)$, where $*$ is the unique element of $G^0$). Then the elements of $C^0(G,A)$ which vanish under application of $d^0$ is just the elements $f$ satisfying $(d^0 f)(g_0) = g_0\cdot f(*)- f(*) = 0$ for all $g_0\in G$, i.e. the elements $a\in A$ such that $g\cdot a=a$. This is precisely $A^G$.

Comment: Crap!  When I saw singleton I was thinking empty set.  I will study your complete answer.  Thank you.

Comment: I think you made an error.  Do you mean $ga = a$ in your second-to last sentence?  I think you mean $g_0 a - a = 0$.  Is that true?  I'm being confused more :)

Comment: Yeah, ther's definintely something wrong here.  I can't accept until that is cleared up.

Comment: Yes, I meant $d^0f(g_0) = g_0\cdot f(*)-f(*) = 0$ - I'll correct it. And relax, it's just a typo (FWIW I was actually thinking of Lie algebra cohomology instead of Lie group).

Comment: I'm getting it now.  $f() \equiv f(*)$.  Is it true that you can take the singleton set to be the trivial group?  That makes sense to me, because you can have arbitrary functions from $1 \in G^0$ to $A$.

Comment: Sure, I guess you can think of $G^0$ as the trivial group if you like, although I don't think it's really all that relevant to be honest.

Comment: Well $G^k$ is a group for all $k \gt 0$.  So it's good that we can take $G^0$ to also be a group.  When the reader sees that all of a sudden they make $G^0$ a singleton _set_ it makes them wonder too much about it, so why throw them off track needlessly.  Everyone knows that $G\times 1 \simeq G$, but what is $G \times \{*\}$.  It's only a set.  I like to keep things simple.